# How to get different messages for the same input?

Tags: python-2.7

i'm trying to get a different messages for the same input, but it's not working ,, for example i want to have message(0) when i run the program and enter a m<0 for the first time but get the different messages for the next times that i enter a m<0

just like Cortona! when you ask her the same question she does not respond the same.

```
def smart(m):
    if m<0 :
        messages(0)
    if m<0 : #for the second entered m!
        messages(1)
    else:
        messages(4)


def messages(n):
    if n==0:
        print "Please enter a positive integer!"
    if n==1:
        print "Dude! i told you a positive integer!"
    elif n==2:
        print "Are you deaf?! A POSITIVE INTEGER!!!"
    elif n==3:
        print "Do you want to f*** with my mind m***********?!"
    elif n==4:
        print "finally"
```

Comment: Can you expand a little bit? All you have is two functions but no other snippet of code about user input and how you are implementing these two functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. Best way to do this sort of thing is to use a while loop to keep prompting the user. Though most people wouldn't need multiple different messages.

```
message = ""
n = 0
while not message.isdigit():
    if n == 0:
        message = raw_input("Please enter a positive integer! ")
    elif n == 1:
        message = raw_input("Dude! i told you a positive integer! ")
    elif n == 2:
        message = raw_input("Are you deaf?! A POSITIVE INTEGER!!! ")
    elif n >= 3:
        message = raw_input("Do you want to f*** with my mind m***********?! ")
    n += 1

if n > 1:
    print "finally"
```